# 2-stacked switches with 2 uplinks to each ASA

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-asa, failover, stacking

My current single uplink from 2-stacked switches to ASA is not enough to cater the link utilization (upload traffic from the 2-stacked switches to ASA). So, I have thought of using 2 uplinks. If I use Etherchannel for the 2-uplinks, then only one link will run in case that one link down instead of failover to standby ASA using 2 standby-uplinks.

Please advise if there is better way of using the 2 uplinks to each ASA and failover to standby ASA in case that one uplink is down.

Please refer the current and new planned diagrams below.

[image]

Comment: What model ASA and switches are you using?

Comment: @JordanHead You may refer to my comment on kaisero's answer.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Comment: Can u please share the fw inside configuration along with the connected stack switch configuration?

Answer (score 3):

Using a 2nd Uplink and using link aggregation (etherchannel) is the right way to go. Keep in mind that your throughput problems might be due to the ASAs limitations (which model do you use?)

Another thing to keep in mind is the load balancing algorithm you use for etherchannel (src-mac, src-dst-mac, src-dst-ip, src-dst-mac-ip). Based on your traffic patterns the default algorithm src-mac might not be the right choice.

Let me know if you need any configuration examples.

#### ASA

```
interface gi0/0
channel-group 1 mode passive

interface gi0/1
channgel-group 1 mode passive
```

#### Switch

```
interface gi1/0/1
channel-group 1 mode active

interface gi2/0/1
channgel-group 1 mode active
```

To verify the status of the link aggregation use the following commands

#### ASA

```
show port-channel summary
```

#### Switch

```
show etherchannel summary
```

both devices should display your configured ports with status **P** (bundled)

Comment: Yes, really appreciate any configuration example. I forgot the exact model number for ASA, but it is 2nd generation 5500 series. Meanwhile, the Cisco switch is 3750.

Comment: I have added sample configuration for LACP.

Comment: Are they both layer-2 etherchannel?

Comment: Yes and No. You would have to add the required configuration on the port-channel interface. I only posted a sample on how to create the channel, l2 configuration on the switch side and l3 configuration on the ASA side is not included.